# Separating lists into a new dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop, list-comprehension, nested-loops

I have a dataframe with one column that contains lists of lists. All the basic lists contain two strings. The lists that contain these basic lists have a variable amount of lists in them.
example:

```
            A
    0 [[1,1],[1,1]]
    1 [[1,1]]
    2 [[1,1],[1,1],[1,1]]
```

I want a new dataframe that has two columns. The first has the first item in each basic list, the second column has the second item. I solved it this way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'A': [[[1,1],[1,1]], [[1,1]], [[1,1],[1,1],[1,1]]]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['A', 'B'])
for x in df.A:
    for i in x:
        n = pd.DataFrame([i], columns = ('A', 'B'))
        df2 = df2.append(n)
```

```
   A  B
0  1  1
0  1  1
0  1  1
0  1  1
0  1  1
0  1  1
```

I know it is not good to loop through a dataframe, but I couldn't figure out how. Here are some failed attempts:

```
for x in df1:
     df2 = [df2.append(pd.DataFrame([i], columns = ('A', 'B'))) for i in x]

df2 = df1.apply(lambda x: df2.append(pd.DataFrame([x[0]], columns = ['name', 'tid'])))
```

If I had got the first list comprehension to work I would have tried to move the for loop to the end of the first list comprehension.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does this do the trick?

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'A': [[[1,1],[1,1]], [[1,1]], [[1,1],[1,1],[1,1]]]})

a = []
b = []
for k in range(len(df)):
    a.append([x[0] for x in df.iloc[k].A])
    b.append([x[1] for x in df.iloc[k].A])

df2 = df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'A': list(itertools.chain(*a)), 'B': list(itertools.chain(*b))})
```

Result:

```
>>> df2
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  1
2  1  1
3  1  1
4  1  1
5  1  1
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have put a graphic description of what I'm going for. I can't figure out how to do that in this reply. I'm trying to get a single '1' in each column. A will have the first element of the list, B will have the second. Hope I described it well enough and thank you for responding.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand that before. Let me know if now I'm answering your question!

Answer (score 0):

quick solution:

```
obj = df['A'].explode()
df1 = pd.DataFrame(obj.tolist(), index=obj.index, columns=['A', 'B'])
```

---

Demo data:

```
df = pd.Series([
    [[1,2],[1,2]],[[3,4]], [[1,2],[1,3],[1,4]]
], name='A').to_frame()
print(df)
```

```
                          A
0          [[1, 2], [1, 2]]
1                  [[3, 4]]
2  [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]]
```

---

use `explode` to transform each element of a list-like to a row, replicating index values.

```
obj = df['A'].explode()
df1 = pd.DataFrame(obj.tolist(), index=obj.index, columns=['A', 'B'])
df_result = df1.groupby(level=0)[['A', 'B']].agg(list)
```

```
df_result

               A          B
    0     [1, 1]     [2, 2]
    1        [3]        [4]
    2  [1, 1, 1]  [2, 3, 4]

df1

       A  B
    0  1  2
    0  1  2
    1  3  4
    2  1  2
    2  1  3
    2  1  4
```

---

use `.apply(pd.Series)` to convert a column with list element to dataframe.

```
df2 = df.A.apply(pd.Series)
print(df2)

       0       1       2
0  [1, 2]  [1, 2]     NaN
1  [3, 4]     NaN     NaN
2  [1, 2]  [1, 3]  [1, 4]
```